# MYSQL group by in subquery but need all data

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have two table , One is **transactions** and another is **expenses**

Transactions table :

```
id  amount  created
1   300     2019-10-01 00:00:00
2   200     2019-11-01 00:00:00
3   230     2019-11-13 00:00:00
4   130     2019-11-13 00:00:00
```

Expenses Table :

```
id  amount  created
1   600     2019-11-13 00:00:00
```

Summation amount for both table, I have written below query which is working fine for me.

```
(SELECT IFNULL(date(t1.created), date(ex.created)) as Date , sum(t1.amount) as ReceiveAmount,ex.amount as ExpensesAmount 
    FROM transactions as t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT sum(e.amount) as amount, created
           FROM expenses as e 
           group by date(e.created)
        ) as ex
    ON date(ex.created) =  date(t1.created)
    GROUP BY date(t1.created))

    UNION

    (SELECT IFNULL(date(t1.created), date(ex.created)) as Date, sum(t1.amount) as Receive,ex.amount as ExpensesAmount 
    FROM transactions as t1

    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT sum(e.amount) as amount, created
        FROM expenses as e 
        group by date(e.created)
    ) as ex
    ON date(t1.created) = date(ex.created)
    GROUP BY date(t1.created)) ORDER BY Date
```

Output :

```
Date        ReceiveAmount   ExpensesAmount  
2019-10-01  300             NULL
2019-11-01  200             NULL
2019-11-13  360             600
```

But now if I want to fetch all amount from both table without summation. I am missing one transaction for date `2019-11-13`.

```
(SELECT IFNULL(date(t1.created), date(ex.created)) as Date , t1.amount as ReceiveAmount,ex.amount as ExpensesAmount 
FROM transactions as t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT e.amount as amount, created
       FROM expenses as e 
       group by date(e.created)
    ) as ex
ON date(ex.created) =  date(t1.created)
GROUP BY date(t1.created))

UNION

(SELECT IFNULL(date(t1.created), date(ex.created)) as Date, t1.amount as Receive,ex.amount as ExpensesAmount 
FROM transactions as t1

RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT e.amount as amount, created
    FROM expenses as e 
    group by date(e.created)
) as ex
ON date(t1.created) = date(ex.created)
GROUP BY date(t1.created)) ORDER BY Date
```

Output  :

```
2019-10-01  300     NULL
2019-11-01  200     NULL
2019-11-13  230     600
```

Here one transaction is missing for date `2019-11-13`.

Expected result :

```
2019-10-01  300     NULL
2019-11-01  200     NULL
2019-11-13  230     600
2019-11-13  130     NULL
```

Here, How can I get my desire result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you could assign `row_number()`s to the records coming from each table with `created` partitions, and then make a `left join`:

```
select t.created, t.amount, e.amount
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by created order by id)  rn 
    from transactions t
) t
left join (
    select
        e.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by created order by id)  rn 
    from expenses e
) e
    on e.created = t.created and e.rn = t.rn
```

---

If any of the two tables may have dates that do not exist in th the other table, then it is a bit more complicated. Basically we need to emulate `full join`, which does not exist in MySQL. Here is one way to do it with `union all`:

```
select created, max(t_amount) t_amount, max(e_amount) e_amount
from (
    select 
        created,
        amount t_amount,
        null e_amount,
        row_number() over(partition by created order by id)  rn 
    from transactions
    union all
    select 
        created,
        null,
        amount,
        row_number() over(partition by created order by id)
    from expenses
) d
group by created, rn
```

Comment: this query is fine for transaction table, but now if expenses table have 2 same date data then it's not working.

Comment: @SatuSultana: that was not showing in your sample data! OK I edited my answer with a solution for that.

Comment: Getting below response 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select
        created,
        amount t_amount,
        null e_amount,
   ' at line 4

Comment: @SatuSultana: just fixed a typo.

Comment: Getting error for last line group by created. 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by created, rn LIMIT 0, 25' at line 17

Comment: @SatuSultana: there is no `limit` in my query. Pls run the query exactly as provided...

Comment: I have used exact same, please check screenshot https://prnt.sc/qa9nxq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204183/discussion-between-satu-sultana-and-gmb).

Comment: @SatuSultana: there was a missing alias on the `union`ed query, which was spotted by Alimon Karim. This should work now!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont't want to sum, you shouldn't group. Other rdbms would throw an error on this.
Without grouping you should get all the records.

But i think you will not get the desired result, since the exepnses will be joined to both transactions on 2019-11-13

Comment: Without group by it's giving duplicate entity for same date result.

Comment: Your example lacks what you expect if there are more than one expences on one day. I thinks thats causes the trouble. I'd suggest to make a simple union with the two tables, having etither RecieveAmount or ExpensesAmount filled